# Text not showing when combined with pseudo-element on li:before

Tags: html, css, pseudo-element, css-content

I have a menu using `<li>`. The example code is as follows:

HTML:

```
<ul>
    <li>Menu 1</li>
    <li>Menu 2</li>
</ul>
```

CSS:

```
li{
    width:190px;
    height:40px;
    padding:3px 10px 3px 50px;  
    border-bottom:1px dotted #003366;
    cursor:pointer;
    line-height:40px;
    background-color: #FFFFFF;
    list-style:none;
    font-weight:bold;                       
    position:relative;
}

li:before{
    content:'';
    position:absolute;
    width:195px;
    height:38px;
    left:50px;
    top:3px;
    background-color: #F9F9F9;
    border:1px solid #CFCFCF;
}
```

When not using the style `li:before` the text in `<li>` will be visible (i.e "Menu 1", "Menu 2") but when used this pseudo-class `li:before` it disappears.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish here? The `:before` content is hiding the text because it is positioned directly over the top of the `<li>` text.

Comment: It does not “disappear”, your :before pseudo elements are simply positioned _over_ the text content of the LI. If you don’t want that – then position them differently.

Answer (score 5):

Firstly, these are [pseudo-elements](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#gen-content), *not* [pseudo-classes](http://www.w3.org/TR/selectors/#pseudo-classes).

That's due to your positioning.

Your `li` element has 50px left padding and 3px top padding.

Your `li:before` pseudo-element has a 50px left offset and a 3px top offset.

This means that your `li:before` pseudo-element is positioned directly on top of your `li`.

You're then giving it a solid background colour, effectively hiding anything beneath it.

[**Here's a demo**](http://jsfiddle.net/JamesD/BKjYq/) showing this more clearly using a `p` element and `p:before` pseudo-element. I've given the pseudo-element some opacity to show how it covers the `p` element.

Comment: Then what should I have to do if I want a background color and wants the text to appear.

Comment: @JerryJones just put the background on your `li` element. I'm not sure what you are trying to achieve by using the pseudo-element in this case otherwise.

Comment: @JerryJones wrap your `li` text in a `span` tag and apply the pseudo-element styling to the `span` instead.

Comment: Did and it's working fine. But still a doubt, if there is any exact method to use these pseudo-element with such conditions.
Any way thanks a lot. Good Day!

Comment: @JerryJones there's no real need to use pseudo elements here as all you're doing is adding a border around text. That's not really what generated content is for.

Comment: Well, I request you to visit the following link to see exactly what I need. Notice the left side menu. http://www.indiantripadviser.com/index.php?searchDesti=Kumarakom%2C+Kottayam&searchDestiC=10700&search=Explore

Comment: @JerryJones I've already looked at your site, that is why I suggested using a `span` instead. Your new problem is that your `span` elements are being styled to 25px width and height with the `#tab_0 > .tab_0_2 > .tab_0_2_1 > .tab_0_2_1_0 > ul > li > span` selector.

Comment: Yeah, In-fact I was using that span to show loading animation using jQuery. I changed the style for span. Thanks for the efforts.